# How to downgrade to python 2.7.5 and make it as default in CentOs7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos7

CentOS7 comes with python 2.7.5 and I followed https://myopswork.com/install-python-2-7-10-on-centos-rhel-75f90c5239a5 and installed python 2.7.10 to meet yugabyte db installation pre-requisites.

Executed the following commands, without considering consequences:

```
alias python="/usr/local/bin/python2.7"
ln -fs /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 50
```

Now, python 2.7.10 became default:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jan 27 2020, 17:09:56) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

rpm lists installed packages list contains, python-2.7.5

```
[root@srvr0 python]# rpm -qa | grep python
...
python-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64
...
```

I am getting error while invoking yum command:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# yum install mysql
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.10 (default, Jan 27 2020, 17:09:56) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I tried installing python 2.7.5:

```
[root@srvr0 python]# rpm -ivh python-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    python-libs(x86-64) = 2.7.5-76.el7 is needed by python-2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64
    python < 2.7.5-86.el7 conflicts with (installed) python-devel-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64
[root@srvr0 python]#
```

Please help me in getting back the default python 2.7.5 along with required default packages/modules.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try uninstall orginal python version , and reinstall your specific python version ,i have forget the exact download command in CentOs7  , but in ubuntu it is `sudo apt-get install python==2.7.5`

after you install , try to use `ln -s python2.7.5 python`,so that every time you call python , it is python version 2.7.5

Comment: i am getting error while invoking automated packages management command, yum and having dependency issues in manual installation as well.